# Approch of desiging database for big site?

Tags: php, mysql, database, scaling

While making a website like facebook

we can follow two approach of database design so please suggest better
Concern is Data Secuirty and Backup Management

Approach 1
Design a table that will hold all the data of the personal and some other table that will hold other keys like image etc 
the problem will come when there are 10 lakhs of entries in the table is it possible thereafter to take backup 
some hosting company wont allow to do so.

Approach 2 
While the user signup assign the separate table to the users in that way user will reach to ten thousand rows in 5 years or so just a assumption

but that means million tables in the database if million user signup and that again a problem i believe

Please suggest better way if anyone can

Comment: Maybe what you want is to hire an expert, not a Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sites the size of Facebook have unique challenges specific to their setups. Facebook, Twitter, Google, etc. all maintain their own forks of database engines and often even write their own, and they'll be using different databases for different purposes. Very little of what they do is going to be applicable to anything you build.

Approach #1 is by far the better. With proper indexes and a good database design, MySQL can support billions of rows. It cannot as easily support millions of tables.

Comment: yes thanks for the suggestions but will it be possible to take backup easily where there are trillions of rows in the table
if i don't bother you so much please suggest backup management strategies if any

Comment: If you have trillions of rows you need an expert (or several) who isn't asking this sort of question and has done work on large database clusters before.